# I have a problem with raising reputation for up votes on my posts

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I answered some question in the MSE and I earned some up votes, but I got no change in my total reputation and I don't know what's the problem. I have this problem for three days and just I earned reputation for accepted answers, not for up votes...

Comment: Yesterday, you hit the reputation cap, cf. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). The same on the first of May.

Comment: Right, but my total reputation doesn't changes...:(

Comment: Can you be more specific? It is normal that your reputation doesn't change when you get an upvote after hitting the reputation cap for the day. On the next day, upvotes again give you reputation [except on CW posts of course], until you hit the cap again (if you do). Do your reputation non-changes go beyond that?

Comment: When somebody give me an upvote, I don't see the raising reputation in my reputation box. Just when the question answered, I see a $+15$ mark on the reputation box and that raise my reputation...

Comment: You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. You hit the reputation cap. Understand?

Comment: I just checked out the reputation tab on your Activity page. All the recent occasions when you didn't get the maximum possible number of points from an unpvote were due to you hitting the daily reputation cap of 200 points from upvotes.

Comment: Thanks everybody...

Comment: Also the +15 reputation received from an accepted answer is [exempt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62973) from the reputation cap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The daily gain of reputation from up-votes and getting proposed edits accepted  is limited  to 200. After that point up-votes have no more effect on the reputation. The counter is reset at the beginning of each day (UTC).

Accepted answers and bounties are not affected by the cap, which is why it is possible to get more than 200 points a day.

More details can be found in the [Help Center's page on reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and in this MSE FAQ [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Another possibility (not relevant in the current case) why one does not get reputation from up-votes is that the post is in Community Wiki mode.

Moreover, it should be noted that the counter in the top-bar only shows an increase in reputation over the last increase. This entails that if, for example, one loses 20 points for some reason and then gets an upvote the counter will not indicate this as one is still below the last reported increase (in this scenario, the upvote had still an effect though).

Comment: This is the right answer...thanks!